# Why does a photon take time to travel from one point to another if it travels with the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity

Shouldn't time stop for the photon and the distance contract to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes from the point of view of external observer. Photon has no proper time indeed.